# django model returning multiple values

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have to convert some of my code from django to PHP

here is the sample code:

```
def loadProduct(id=0)
  if id==0:
      product=BaseProduct.products.all()[0];
  else:
       product = BaseProduct.objects.get(id=id);
  color = product.color
  images = color.images.all();
  return {'product':product, 'color':{'color':color, 'images':images}}
```

now i have some basic knowledge of django..
but not able to understand this return type in this...

can any one help me on this...

Comment: Python data structures - http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

The method is returning a dictionary, which is roughly equivalent to an associative array in PHP.

Comment: thank u for helping so quickly....but i want to know ... the returning array in this is multidimesional??

Comment: Yes, `color` is another dictionary (another associative array)